# Sort given 2d array in order of ascending by python3.x

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am a python beginner, please help me with this python case.

Sort given 2d array in order of ascending.Flatten the 2D array, and sort it such that first sort order is the first number, second sort order is the second number'''# Example:

```
input_arr = [
    ['55-29', '55-32', '62-3', '84-38'],
    ['36-84', '23-53', '22-58', '48-15'],
    ['72-80', '48-6', '11-86', '73-23'],
    ['93-51', '55-11', '93-49', '72-10'],
    ['93-66', '71-32', '16-75', '55-9']
]
 ouput_arr = ['11-86', '16-75', '22-58', '23-53', '36-84', '48-6', '48-15', '55-9', '55-11', '55-29', '55-32', '62-3', '71-32', '72-10', '72-80', '73-23', '84-38', '93-49', '93-51', '93-66'] 

def sort_2d_array(input_arr=input_arr) -> list:    
    #TODO
    pass
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve] to increase your chances of getting an answer to your question instead of getting it closed down.

Comment: Please read [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
you need to flatten your list into single list like this

```
tmp = [t for x in input_arr for t in x]
```

then do the sorting based on first element before the `-`, like this

```
print(list(sorted(tmp,key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))))
```

this will give you your desired output.

```
['11-86', '16-75', '22-58', '23-53', '36-84', '48-15', '48-6', '55-29', '55-32', '55-11', '55-9', '62-3', '71-32', '72-80', '72-10', '73-23', '84-38', '93-51', '93-49', '93-66']
```

for second condition you can try

```
print(list(sorted(tmp,key=lambda x: (int(x.split('-')[0]) , int(x.split('-')[1])))))
```

this will give you

```
['11-86', '16-75', '22-58', '23-53', '36-84', '48-6', '48-15', '55-9', '55-11', '55-29', '55-32', '62-3', '71-32', '72-10', '72-80', '73-23', '84-38', '93-49', '93-51', '93-66']
```

Comment: That doesn't do the second sorting with the part after `-`

Comment: @JacquesGaudin thanks for point it out